# Shifting Focus Of Page Upon Buttonpress

Tags: jquery, button, click, focus, blur

I'm trying to shift my focus from the current page to the note section after pressing the note button. This is what I have tried

```
$('#[% QuestionName() %]').focus(function() {

});

$( document ).ready(function(){

    $("#note-button").click(function() {
        $("[id$='note']").focus();
    }
});
$('#[% QuestionName() %]').blur(function(){
});
```

But it's not working, I can't get the focus to shift to the note section. I was trying to use

```
if $("#note-button").click(function() {
```

but that was giving an error message. I tried to attach the button id to a click function, although I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way. I know that the `$("[id$='note']")` selector itself should work because I have used it successfully in other contexts. What might be the problem with my code, is there an alternative way to go about this besides using if?

Comment: can you post your relevant html as well?

Comment: Note: press F10 OR 
`<body><html>
<button type="button" id="note-button" onClick="checkNoteButton()">NOTE</button>`

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: `function checkNoteButton(){
 $("#[% QuestionName() %]_div").css('display', 'block')
 };

</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?
*Edited to put focus on a div*

```js
const shiftFocus = () => {
 const thing3 = document.querySelectorAll('div')[2];
  thing3.focus();
}
```

```css
button{
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  margin: .2em 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='shiftFocus()'>Click me</button>
<br />
<div type='text' tabindex="0">
div 1
</div>  <br />
<div type='text' tabindex="0">
div 2
</div>  <br />
<div type='text' tabindex="0">
div 3
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou! I don't think this is exactly what I wanted to do though. I already have a note button that exists on the page, "note-button" that calls up the note section, and the selector ("[id$='note']") works for this note section on every page. I am already calling up the note section by pressing the note button, but I just want to shift the focus to it when it is called

Comment: What type of element exactly are you trying to put focus on?

Comment: It's a div element

Comment: How exactly do I use it?

Comment: It seems to be shifting the focus to another question on the next page, I'll see if I can work with it a bit, thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Appreciate a vote if you can use for a solution. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help! I still haven't been able get it to work though, I did play around with this for a while but didn't have any luck. I've given up on the problem pretty much, it wasn't absolutely vital for me so I spent a fair amount of time on it but I've moved on to other work.